# Do I need a live site to test Facebook Connect?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook connect with nmy social network site, currently users create and login with there own account on my site but I am wanting to allow users to basicly create a new account on my site but use the facebook connect to login, I think it will be pretty easy on my site the way I have my user database setup, I have a login table and a user table so with facebook connect the user would just have a user table and not a login table record.

Ok my problem is my site is currently not online, it is all localhost right now, when doing facebook connect for testing/integration do you have to have an active domain?  I know you have to use your domain in the signup process at facebook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it works with localhost. This one also says it works: http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2009/02/testing-facebook-connect-locally.html

Answer (score 4):

What I do is place the site's hostname in `etc\hosts` file, directed to 127.0.0.1 -- eg:

```
127.0.0.1  mysite.com
```

if i need to browse to the real `mysite.com` then i'll use `http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: I do that to but I am not sure because facebook wants you to put some file on the server that it can comunicate with and with this method I can communicate with facebook but they can't communicate to my domain if it is offline

Comment: yes but that file is fetched by your browser, so it all just works