# setting up and testing facebook connect on local server such as xampp

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to set up and test facebook connect on a local server such as xampp?

I am currently developing a login/registration using dreamweaver cs5 and would like to test facebook connect with the phpmyadmin database on my xampp server.

Is there a solution to this problem without me requiring to move my application to real public website?

I would appreciate any advice on workarounds available.

many thanks :-)

Comment: What is your actual question? What didnt work, what error messages did you recieve? Have you tried it yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255591/using-local-area-network-address-as-facebook-canvas-url

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running facebook application on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers before, I think you should be able to solve the problem by giving localhost a fake domain (in your hosts file). See [Do I need a live site to test Facebook Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966045/do-i-need-a-live-site-to-test-facebook-connect), for example.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create Facebook testing application (something like "YourProject - DEV") and set your localhost URLs in its configuration options.